# the excel connection manager is not supported in 64 bit version of SSIS as no OLEDB provider is availale

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to execute an SSIS package and getting the below message. Could you share how to fix this?

the excel connection manager is not supported in 64 bit version of SSIS as no OLEDB provider is availale

Answer (score 5):

For 2010 visual studio (but will be similar in other versions;

1. Right click on the project, properties
2. Configuration Management ->Debugging
3. Set Run64BitRuntime to false